# Pandas: create column with end of quarter date given year column and quarter column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and have been struggling with this easy task. Given the following dataframe:

```
    Year  Qt  Value
0   2010  2   17
1   2015  1   11
2   2020  1   86
```

I want to create another column with the date of quarter end:

```
    Year  Qt  Value Date
0   2010  2   17    30/06/2010
1   2015  1   11    31/03/2015
2   2020  1   86    31/03/2020
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with this `pd.to_datetime` to change the column 'Year' and 'Qt' to date and then add an offset to the [end of the Quarter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd.html) with :

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str)+'Q'+df['Qt'].astype(str))\
  + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()
0   2010-06-30
1   2015-03-31
2   2020-03-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: You know, I don't think I ever used tseries.offsets before.  Thanks for the solution.  +1

Comment: @ScottBoston I was recently comparing trading data with the previous business days so I ended up to use these `DateOffsets`. Your solution taught me something too, but `pd.Period` does not seem to accept a serie-like object instead of str, I was a bit surprised.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `pd.Period` and `end_time`:

```
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Period(f"{x['Qt']}Q{x['Year']}" ).end_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Year  Qt  Value        Date
0  2010   2     17  30/06/2010
1  2015   1     11  31/03/2015
2  2020   1     86  31/03/2020
```